# Set ID attribute dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have recursively partial view, this is part of it

```
<ul>
    @if (item != null)
    {
        <li> 
            @item.ActionName
            @if (item.CMSModels.Count > 0)
            {
                @Html.Partial("Childrens", item)
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I want to set ID attribute dynamically to `<li>`. For example, I want to get `<li id =@item.ActionName+@item.ControllerName>`. 
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
   <li id="@string.Concat(item.ActionName,item.ControllerName)">
```